# PHP Curl - How to download a file which is generated on demand

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to download a `.xls` file which is generated once I press the download button (rather than downloading a file which is already existing in a location on the server).

I tried the following solution:

```
$datapost = curl_init();
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($datapost, CURLOPT_FILE, fopen('file.xls', 'w+')); //auto write to file
ob_start();
$response = curl_exec($datapost);
ob_end_clean();
curl_close($datapost);
```

When I check the `file.xls`, it is empty, but it's supposed to have thousands of rows populated with data. I believe I am doing something wrong in the approach of downloading a file which is generated on demand.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: To less information i think. Which script will generate the file? Maybe you want this: `generate.php?file.xml`? Then you have to create the `generate.php` file first ;-)

Comment: I am trying to download this file from an external website. I have no access to any of their side. This is all I have. But thank you :)

Comment: Do you try `file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/file.xls');`? Or do you really need curl?

Comment: @u-nik - The file is generated on demand, it is not in a specific location on the server. Also, I need to log in, meaning I do need curl.

Comment: @dzerow Please provide your $url.

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn it's protected, I'm not meant to share. It's like an "export to xls" button, does it help?

Comment: @dzerow I must try it on browser so can convert to PHP. You now? I can't guess and code.